# Is there anyway in java.1.8 to pass/store function references in a Map as in scala?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to covert previous scala code to java 1.8 code.

In scala , I was using a Map to store all respective classes function references.
As shown here in Driver.scala class getAllDefinedProcessors() function.

https://gist.github.com/shatestest/86ae9559c6114999e13a6eec3c80ec2b

```
object Driver {

 ...

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

   val procs :  LinkedHashMap[String, (DataFrameReader, SparkSession, String) => Unit] = getAllDefinedProcessors();


       for ( key <- procs.keys){
            procs.get(key).map{
                println("process started for loading column family : " + key);
               fun => fun(ora_df_options_conf,spark,columnFamilyName)
         }
        }

     }

     def getAllDefinedProcessors(): LinkedHashMap[String, (DataFrameReader, SparkSession, String) => Unit] = {
         LinkedHashMap(
          "bm_vals" -> new BMValsProcessor().process,
          "bm_vals2" -> new BMValsProcessor2().process
        )
     }
}
```

How to convert this equivalent java 1.8 functional features?
Does the java 1.8 support functional references ?
If so how to proceed further ?
Any alternative way for the same ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but here's a stab at a solution. The java functional features do exist, but they're actually just plain interfaces, and there's some special syntax for creating these painlessly. Unfortunately, I don't think your specific scenario has a pre-defined function class, but here are two, plus a way to generate the one you're missing:

```java
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Junk {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Function<Integer, Integer> square = x -> x * x;  // This is basically your lambda function
    System.out.println("This should print 9: " + square.apply(3));

    Consumer<String> prefixedText = text -> System.out.println("This is crazy, but " + text); // there's nothing special about the variable naming

    prefixedText.accept("it actually works!");
    // Per java, there are a few types of lambdas. Here are 3 that come to mind -- they're all under java.util.function
    // Function (also BiFunction, which takes 2 arguments) -- takes an argument, produces a result
    // Consumer (also BiConsumer) -- takes an argument, but produces nothing
    // Supplier -- takes no arguments, and produces  something

    // The abstractions they have only defined for a particular subset of function types though. it looks like you need a TriConsumer...
    TriConsumer<Integer, Integer, Integer> iDunno = (a, b, c) -> System.out.println("I can't think of an example of a tri consumer. But you get the idea. " + a + b + c);
    iDunno.accept(1, 2, 3);
  }

  interface TriConsumer<T,U,V> implements {
    public abstract void accept(T one, U two, V three);
  }
}
```

If you wanted to place these into a map, they'd obviously all need to share the same type/generic, but you could then make a hashmap to hold them all:

```java
HashMap<String, TriConsumer> someMap = new HashMap<>();
someMap.put("key1", (a,b,c) -> System.out.println());
someMap.put("key2", (a,b,c) -> /*etc*/);
```

One thing to keep in mind -- these functions can't have exceptions. If you want to have exceptions, you need to bake that into the interface -- e.g. `interface MyFunction<T, U>{ public U apply(T t) throws IOException{} }`
if you needed/wanted to be able to throw exceptions in your lambda function when doing some io processing.

One more note: the return is implicit for a single command function. If you want a longer function, you can wrap it in `{}` as normal, but then you need to do an explicit return.

Comment: thank you , I used Map of objects instead , where i get object and invoke the method directly.